# What is the meaning of 准新 in 由于二手车市场准新车越来越多...?

Tags: meaning

I have this sentence:

> 由于二手车市场准新车越来越多，加上价格原因，特别是二手车保值率的提高与稳定，使得交易日趋活跃。

Does 准新车 mean 'nearly new cars'?

Comment: http://baike.baidu.com/link?url=b--gSyb1Z5_aSbTvem9N9BbGa7bX6g6vBER1COwBH5emIS91vrLRjRwOZPxU2u-uKn-JXHAPmlFKrvRIL3oXia 外文名
Quasi new car

Comment: and by quasi new car you mean nearly new? quasi = like but not as

Comment: @Pedroski I believe the U.S. idiom is 'used like new'.

Comment: BTW, for your information, the corresponding Traditional Chinese characters are "準新車".

Comment: Haha, I have enough trouble with Simplfied, I'll never learn Traditional!

Comment: "Simplified" does not imply "Easy".  XD

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I think so. And it's just like someone who has just bought a new car and doesn't want keep it anymore, selling it on the secondhand market. Then the car he sold can be called “准新车”. “准” in Chinese always means nearly but not exactly. For instance, “准老婆” means your girlfriend and she is very likely to marry with you in the near future.

Comment: Thanks, I like that, have an upvote! I'll call my girlfriend that, but I don't want to get married any time soon!

Comment: Well, is she a Chinese?

Comment: And if she is, I believe she may prefer you to call her "老婆大人“. hahahahehehe~

Comment: 泰州的！泰州话很奇怪的。Very strange indeed!